# how to get data from Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
  $("#sub_category_id").change(function(){
        // alert($(this).val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{{route('get.all.subcategory.type')}}",
            data: 'id=' + $(this).val(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#sub_category_id").html(data).alert(["type"]);
            }
        });

    });
```

My controller:

```
public function getSubType(){

    $subCategory = Category::where('status' , 0)->where('parent_id' , '!=' , 0)->get('type');
    return $subCategory;
}
```

Route:

```
 Route::get('get_sub_type', 'QuestionController@getSubType')->name('get.all.subcategory.type');
```

I want to get the type of subcategory from question view with jquery ajax. How I can get the type of subcategory with ajax and jquery which I have saved in sub-category view.

something like when I select a subcategory from questions then it shows me alert with its type which I saved in a sub-category. when I select a subcategory from question view it should show me the category type in an alert. if you need more data you can ask.

[image: subcategory image]
[image: question image]

Comment: `return response()->json($subCategory)` as you need to return the data in json format

Comment: Have u called request object in controller to fetch sub category?

Comment: No. I dont know how to do.

Comment: `echo json_encode($subCategory);` instead of return. and add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax call.

Comment: still i'm not getting type of subcategory

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sub_category_id").change(function(){
        // alert($(this).val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{{route('get.all.subcategory.type')}}",
            data: 'id=' + $(this).val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#sub_category_id").html(data).alert(["type"]);
            }
        });

});
```

Controller:

```
public function getSubType(){

    $subCategory = Category::where('status' , 0)->where('parent_id' , '!=' , 0)->get('type');
    echo json_encode($subCategory);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller part, change your return from :

```
return $subCategory;
```

to:

```
 return response()->json($subCategory);
```

it will become :

```
public function getSubType(){

$subCategory = Category::where('status' , 0)->where('parent_id' , '!=' , 0)->get('type');
return response()->json($subCategory);  }
```